# xypic: curved invisible arrows

Tags: xy-pic

I want to create two invisible arrows so I can link between them, the problem is that when I try the make these arrows curved they become no longer invisible?

Here is a sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{A
 \ar@{}@/^{2.4pc}/[d] \\
 B
}
\]
\end{document}
```

It gives the following graph:

[image: graph]

What I want is to make the arrow going from $A$ to $B$ invisible, but it doesn't work!

So what's wrong with this latex code?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I edited your question to have a real Minimal example (and not a complicated code of your whole diagram). I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Maybe you should open a new question for your edit, because it's not the same problem. If you do so, I would be happy to give you an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, it doesn't work out of the box with the standard empty type.

You have 2 solutions.

1. Define explicitely a new empty directional for the shaft.
2. Show to xy-pic that you really want an empty shaft with `@{{}{ }{}}` (notice the space in the shaft position).

Here is a code that shows the two possibilities :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\newdir{:=}{{}} %creates an empty shaft directional, the ":=" is chosen "randomly"
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{A
 \ar@{{}{ }{}}@/^2pc/[d]^{}="a"
 \ar@{:=}@/_2pc/[d]^{}="b" \\
 B
 \ar@{->}"a";"b"
}
\]
\end{document}
```

And the result :

[image]

Comment: Thank you Matsaya, even if I do not understant how it works, I want to try it on LyX, the problem is that LyX do not permit to insert spaces in equations areas, have you any idea on how to do it?

Comment: @ubugnu, without space you can use the first solution (the `\newdir{:=}{{}}`) if your able to add command in the preamble. One possible solution to doing that is to edit your Lyx file with a text editor. Put the line `\newdir{:=}{{}}` somewhere in the preamble. Then when you use LyX on your document you will be able to use the `:=`directional to have empty arrows.

Comment: @Matasaya,Thank you it worked, now I'm wondering if I can connect two distant arrows with an arrow (see my edit) without using invisible arrows?

Comment: @ubugnu, I strongly recommand you to ask a new question for your edit because this it clearly a separate question. It's better to separate different questions to fit the purpose of the site.The short answer is yes, you can (and I have the code).